# What is the meaning and etymology of "cod-French" accent?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, accent, french

Here's a [passage](http://www.historytoday.com/marc-morris/william-conqueror-reassessed?mc_cid=aff25a943d&mc_eid=04755452df) referring to re-enactments of the Battle of Hastings:

> As you might expect, the English king, Harold Godwinson, comes across
>   as an essentially decent chap, albeit weary and exasperated. By
>   contrast, his adversary, Duke William of Normandy, sounds like a
>   maniac, ranting furiously in a cod-French accent – Napoleon filtered
>   through the lens of Hitler.

So what is a cod-French accent? I've read somewhere that it means to pronounce English words in a comical faux-French way. This makes sense but I am left wondering where the term came from.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Are you asking about the etymology of the adjective cod that means, false/phoney? It seems the [etymology is unknown](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cod#Etymology_3).

Comment: For some history and etymological speculation [Cod (mock) -- The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/04/cod-mock/) might be of interest

Comment: It's a shame the outcome of that article is "We have no clue on the origin of cod (mock)" !

Comment: As a curiosity, "dutch" is also used to mean "mock" or "fake" - dutch oven, dutch date etc - although, confusingly, most people don't even realize that's the sense anymore.  (Which seems quite rude by the way!)  That usage of "dutch" is because of obscure historical issues from around the 1600s.

Comment: hi @Laure.  Just for the record, the question seems absolutely clear and straightforward.  This sentence for instance *"What is the meaning and etymology of “cod-French” accent?"* couldn't be clearer?

Comment: @JoeBlow If the question means "what is the meaning of cod-French" then it's off topic since the meaning of adjective cod can be found in a dictionary. And OP does not ask clearly about etymology, he does not use the word, just writes... "where did the term come from."

Comment: @Laure Have you read the title of the question.....? :)

Comment: hi Laure, if you think it's off-topic, that's totally reasonable.  But it is not in the slightest unclear, I have to say!  (The phrase "where did the term come from" is absolutely clear, and I use it when asking etymology questions!)  Anyway no big deal.

Comment: Yes I did, but what is written afterwards does not follow. What's the point of asking for the meaning of word that is in a dictionary? I thought ELU was not asking for that sort of things.

Comment: @JoeBlow You've overlooked 'Double Dutch' in your list!

Comment: @Laure *"the meaning of adjective cod can be found in a dictionary"* Depends on which dictionary you use: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cod) doesn't have it. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cod) also has no entry for cod as an adjective. (There's verb/noun entries that are close, but the definitions don't obviously apply.) The meaning here is apparently a regional one: while it might be prevalent in your part of the world, it's unknown in others, and hence does not necessarily appear in dictionaries for, e.g. Americans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Cod* as an adjective is an informal British word for "[not authentic; fake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cod)". It is of uncertain origin according to oxforddictionaries.com.

Here is a celebrated example of a cod-French accent: [French Taunter - Monty Python and the Holy Grail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8yjNbcKkNY).

Comment: Or look up "'Allo 'allo" on youtube with the bonus of cod-German as well

Comment: I was wondering, regarding Peter Sellers (or indeed Steve Martin) in Pink Panther, would you use "cod-French" there?  ie when it's extremely broadly comic?

Comment: May be an abbreviation of *codger*, according to the OED. *1851   D. Jerrold St. Giles & St. James (new ed.) ii, in Writings I. 14   And that's what they'll do with you, my little codger.*

Comment: It's okay for cod-French and cod-German to be used for comic-effect in the BBC's much loved 'Allo 'Allo!, but the cod-French spoken by the UK's Prime Minsters Ted Heath & Margaret Thatcher made BREXIT inevitable. "Tant pis".

Answer (score 4):

## *À l’eau, c’est l’heure!*

In *Cassell’s Dictionary of Slang* by Jonathon Green (2<sup>nd</sup> edition, 2006), we find this [set of related entries for *cod*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=*cod+version*,+a+burlesque+of+a+well-known+play&source=bl&ots=2zkTO2gmD2&sig=u7vXAzVAULES-kF9BHn2E4piWMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4nI7tzNDPAhXBJx4KHb5FCgEQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=*cod%20version*%2C%20a%20burlesque%20of%20a%20well-known%20play&f=false):

> **cod**, *n.*² 1 [mid–late 17C] a friend; thus *honest cod*, a good friend. 2 [late 17C–18C] a fellow. 3 [late 17C+] a fool. [(2) in this context *cod* has been linked to SE *codger*, and it is found as an abbr., but *cod* is a much earlier word; (3) ? ᴄᴏᴅ’ꜱ ʜᴇᴀᴅ n.]
>
> **cod**, *n.*⁶ [20C+] (*orig. Irish*) 1. a joke, a hoax, a leg-pull, a parody. 2. deception, deceipt, a lie; thus, *cod-acting* foolish behaviour. [ᴄᴏᴅ v. (2)]
>
> **cod** *adj.*¹ [1950s+] fake, parodic; usu. in combs., e.g. *cod-Russian, code-typewriter* etc. [ᴄᴏᴅ v. (2) + ? play on ꜰɪꜱʜʏ adj.³ (1); note theatrical jargon *cod version*, a burlesque of a well-known play]
>
> **cod** *v.* 1 [18C] to cheat, to defraud. 2 [mid-19C+] (*also* **codd**) to tease, to hoax. [ᴄᴏᴅ n.² (3)]

The OED doesn’t seem to think it can come from *codger*, and neither does Green here.

I’m more familiar with the use of *cod* in this way for Latin than for French. If you search for *cod Latin* on Wikipedia, it brings up [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Latin):

> **Dog Latin**, also known as **Cod Latin, macaronic Latin, mock Latin**, or **Canis Latinicus**,[1] refers to the creation of a phrase or jargon in imitation of Latin,[2] often by "translating" English words (or those of other languages) into Latin by conjugating or declining them as if they were Latin words. Unlike the similarly named language game Pig Latin (a form of playful spoken code), Dog Latin is more of a humorous device for invoking scholarly seriousness.

That article also references the comic work [*Mots d’Heures: Gousses, Rames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mots_d%27Heures) (*viz.* “Mother Goose Rhymes”) as being one deliberately written in “cod-French”. These are related to the phenomenon that has of late come to be called a [*mondegreen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen).

These mock versions of other languages have a long history.  One fairly recent one, deriving from the early days of the computer age, is in cod-German and has come to be known as the [*blinkenlights meme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights); from Wikipedia:

> **ACHTUNG!**
>   ALLES TURISTEN UND NONTEKNISCHEN LOOKENPEEPERS!
>   DAS KOMPUTERMASCHINE IST NICHT FÜR DER GEFINGERPOKEN UND MITTENGRABEN! ODERWISE IST EASY TO SCHNAPPEN DER SPRINGENWERK, BLOWENFUSEN UND POPPENCORKEN MIT SPITZENSPARKEN.
>   IST NICHT FÜR GEWERKEN BEI DUMMKOPFEN. DER RUBBERNECKEN SIGHTSEEREN KEEPEN DAS COTTONPICKEN HÄNDER IN DAS POCKETS MUSS.
>   ZO RELAXEN UND WATSCHEN DER BLINKENLICHTEN.

This sort of [macaronic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaronic_language) is used by Umberto Eco to good effect in various novels of his, famously including in *Il Nome della Rosa* (English: The Name of the Rose) from the mouth of his character Salvatore:

> “Penitenziagite! Vide quando draco venturus est a rodegarla l’anima tua! La mortz est super nos! Prega che vene lo papa santo a liberar nos a malo de todas le peccata! Ah ah, ve piase ista negromanzia de Domini Nostri Iesu Christi! Et anco jois m’es dols e plazer m’es dolors... Cave el diabolo! Semper m’aguaita in qualche canto per adentarme le carcagna. Ma Salvatore non est insipiens! Bonum monasterium, et aqui se magna et se priega dominum nostrum. Et el resto valet un figo seco. Et amen. No?"

Since that’s macaronic Italian not macaronic English, it may be harder to see for those without a fair knowledge of Latin and its many daughter tongues that Eco is here weaving together. So here’s the would-be English translation from the English version of Eco’s novel:

> “Penitenziagite! Watch out for the draco who cometh in futurum to gnaw your anima! Death is super nos! Pray the Santo Pater come to liberar nos a malo and all our sin! Ha ha, you like this negromanzia de Domini Nostri Jesu Christi! Et anco jois m’es dols e plazer m’es dolors.... Cave el diabolo! Semper lying in wait for me in some angulum to snap  at my heels. But Salvatore is not stupidus! Bonum  monasterium, and aquí refectorium and pray to dominum nostrum. And the resto is not worth merda. Amen. No?”

Comment: The Tower of Babel stands proud on ELU.